Docker can't connect to internet in any mode on fresh Ubuntu install
I have installed docker-ce on a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 installation. (I have also tried 22.04)
However, there is no internet connection in the container:
sudo docker run busybox nslookup google.com
Results in  ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
It does not matter if I use the --network=host or --dns=8.8.8.8 options. I've tried restarting docker, and wiping the system, but nothing seems to work.
The docker network interface exists. If I run ifconfig on the host I get:
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:b3ff:fefa:e967  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:b3:fa:e9:67  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 198  bytes 11640 (11.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 229  bytes 27906 (27.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

and if I run it within the docker container I get:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:02  
          inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:220 (220.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

sudo docker network ls output is reasonable:
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
e79e1a540122   bridge    bridge    local
11adb769cc27   host      host      local
afd4a1660904   none      null      local


Which looks correct afaict. How do I go about debugging this? It is surprising to me, bc I thought "docker on ubuntu" should be a really well-worn path.
Thank you for any help!

sigh, well, it seems that this problem resolved itself after enough restarts of the machines, so I have no idea of the root cause of the issue I spent all day yesterday on. But along the way, I did find some debugging tips for any poor soul who finds themselves here:
The busybox image is great for including all the network utilities. A good place to start is to watch traffic on the docker0 network interface on the host machine with sudo tcpdump -i docker0
Then fire some traffic from the container with sudo docker run busybox nslookup google.com. If nslookup works, then everything should work.
